# Select, Case in if-else statement requires double inputs

Tags: bash, shell-script

I need to find out where is the problem. I need to write a script that prompts users to make Yes/No choice in if/else statement. In general I have a bash script that runs like this

```
if CONDITION; then
    COMMANDS1
else
    COMMANDS2
    echo "Does this look okay to you? (WARNING: This action will not be recoverable!) :          
    PS3="Select a number: "
    select yn in "Yes" "No"
    do
          case $yn in
               "Yes" )
                echo "Ok!" ; break ;;
                "No" )
                echo "Aborted!" ; break ;;
          esac
    done
fi
```

But when I run the script, it shows

```
Does this look okay to you? (WARNING: This action will not be recoverable!)
1) Yes
2) No
Select a number: (I have to press anything here)
Select a number: (Only this input does something).
```

I ran the script with sh -vx and it shows that it runs both select and case separately. How do I make sure I only need one input?

```
+ echo 'Does this look okay to you? (WARNING: This action will not be recoverable!) : '
Does this look okay to you? (WARNING: This action will not be recoverable!) : 
+ PS3='Select a number: '
+ select yn in '"Yes"' '"No"'
1) Yes
2) No
Select a number: 1
+ case "$yn" in
Select a number: 2
+ case "$yn" in
+ echo 'Aborted!'
Aborted!
+ break
```

Thank you very much!

EDIT: I am running bash on Mac OS 14.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. I suspect there is text remaining in `stdin` from some previous input, to which you are adding some input, and (crucially) a newline.

You could add a `*` default case, and print what is stored in `REPLY`. I would probably want to show that in visible form, to identify what is pending:

```
( * ) printf '%s' "${REPLY}" | od -A n -t x1ac;;
```

I would also quote `"$yn"`, as I am unsure what `case` would do with multiple words here.

Comment: You are right! I just found out that there is a bug in the remind program which produces some rubbish text then passes to the "Select a number". You have any idea how can I suppress this error output from the remind program?

Comment: `case` does not do word-splitting or filename-expansion on its first argument, so unquoted is OK. (https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-case)

Comment: I have found a workaround. I parse the output of the buggy software to a text document and start working from there. The problem now disappears!